# Add extra column in jquery Datatable after calling custom PHP function on it?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, datatables

I have displayed Data from multiple tables in jquery datatable with Yajra library of Laravel.

Now i want to add extra variable/Column in Result of Database query.At the moment it gives 7 columns in output , now i want to add extra column which will give me output after i pass result column's ID into one PHP function.

For example. Current query give me Array of 10 Row with 7 Column, Now i want to use ID of each and want to pass it in User defined PHP  Function which give me output and that out put i want to display in jquery datatable.

Comment: can you show code please so we could help you

Comment: Thanks @NicolasD for Quick Reply, But i solved it already.

Comment: So delete your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by addColumn method Yajra Of Laravel Library.
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/wiki/Add-Column